# Django-CMS with Grappelli messed up the layout for admin cms pages

Tags: django, django-admin, django-cms, django-grappelli

I just installed grappelli into a Django-CMS site by following the standard routine - `pip install django-grappelli`, add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`, add in the url pattern, then `syncdb` and `collectstatic`. However, although all the other pages in the admin area look great with the new "theme", the layout for CMS Pages settings in Django-CMS (the drag 'n drop interface) are all messed up.

Why is that, and is there a fix for this, yet?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks, Brandon for your reply. Is there a way to completely uninstall grappelli without causing any problems? Right now, the default admin's javascripts are messed up after I got rid of grappelli from `INSTALLED_APPS`. In particular, these are from the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: grp is not defined actions.js:134
Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined admincompat.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined collapse.js:24
Uncaught ReferenceError: django is not defined :8000/admin/cms/page/2/:942
```

Comment: Grappelli and Django-CMS are not compatible afaik.

Comment: Your edit has made this into a completely different question (to which the answer is probably "delete your `STATIC_ROOT` directory and run `collectstatic` again). Perhaps just delete this question and re-ask any parts of it that are still outstanding?

Comment: supervacuo's suggestion works! Thanks.

Comment: @supervacuo, this is really strange. I didn't do the collectstatic in the first place because I am using the django microserver, in a development localhost machine. I uninstall grappelli and left everything as it was (I used github to go to my master version) and still got the error. I actually had to create another virtualenvironment and reinstall all the packages again with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution - it involves setting up a subdomain to server a version of your site with grappelli removed and serving static media from a different directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900801/473285

Answer (score 0):

Grappelli also conflicts with the stock Django admin. Another solution that work is, If you have removed Grappelli from `INSTALLED_APPS` also remove its url configurations too..

from url configuration **remove this line**.

```
path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))
```